# laravel wont set header during gopay payment integration

Tags: laravel, curl, header, integration, payment

I have a problem with payment integration to my laravel project. It is a GOPAY REST API.

It should by default set request headers with Accept, Content-type and Authorization where the token is stored. Problem is that it doesnt set my request headers. I used the same thing in a normal script which included the SDK and it worked correctly. However in my laravel project it just doesnt work. The SDK uses Curl to set headers and i think there is somewhere the problem.

I also didnt find any similar problem, and i definitely didnt google anyone who integrated GoPay into Laravel.

Pay method in my controller

```
  //minimal configuration
    $gopay = GoPay\payments([
        'goid' => '8583340073',
        'clientId' => '1162442589',
        'clientSecret' => 'eDxNQ3ru',
        'isProductionMode' => false,
        'scope' => GoPay\Definition\TokenScope::ALL,
        'language' => GoPay\Definition\Language::CZECH],
    ['logger' => new GoPay\Http\Log\PrintHttpRequest()]);





    $response = $gopay->createPayment([
        'payer' => [
            'default_payment_instrument' => PaymentInstrument::BANK_ACCOUNT,
            'allowed_payment_instruments' => [PaymentInstrument::BANK_ACCOUNT],
            'default_swift' => BankSwiftCode::FIO_BANKA,
            'allowed_swifts' => [BankSwiftCode::FIO_BANKA, BankSwiftCode::MBANK],
            'contact' => [
                'first_name' => 'Zbynek',
                'last_name' => 'Zak',
                'email' => 'test@test.cz',
                'phone_number' => '+420777456123',
                'city' => 'C.Budejovice',
                'street' => 'Plana 67',
                'postal_code' => '373 01',
                'country_code' => 'CZE',
            ],
        ],

        'target' => ['type' => 'ACCOUNT', 'goid' => '8583340073'],
        'currency' => Currency::CZECH_CROWNS,
        'order_number' => '001',
        'order_description' => 'pojisteni01',
        'items' => [
            ['name' => 'item01', 'amount' => 50],
            ['name' => 'item02', 'amount' => 100],
        ],
        'recurrence' => [
            'recurrence_cycle' => Recurrence::DAILY,
            'recurrence_period' => "7",
            'recurrence_date_to' => '2016-12-31'
        ],
        'additional_params' => [
            array('name' => 'invoicenumber', 'value' => '2015001003')
        ],
        'callback' => [
            'return_url' => 'http://www.hume.cz/public',
            'notification_url' => 'http://www.hume.cz/public'
        ]

    ]);
```

I think that somehow laravel changes the headers and doesnt allow the SDK to do it. If you know anything please help me. If you need any extra information, please just ask.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: come on guys, noone had the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for handling GoPay payments with Laravel. Install, update config with your credentials and start using GoPay facade to createPayment or another function from official SDK.

I have eshop in production with this my own package and everything works fine.

https://github.com/hazestudio/laravel-gopay-sdk